# Вытащить записи содержимого поля которого превышает

Tags: mysql

Как в mysql выбрать все записи по полю, содержимого которого превышает 10 символов?

Comment: length(поле) > 10

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE LENGTH(field_name) > 10;
```

Здесь `table_name` - имя таблицы, а `field_name` - имя поля, содержимое которого вы хотите проверить.